# Question about a argument in using Task

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

Guys, I used to use a method like `Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(()=>{}), cancellationToken);`

I have a question about the second argument `cancellationToken`. Because `cancellationToken` is a variable in my method, in the lambda expression, I can cancel my task using the field just like the msdn does; I'm not sure it's recommend. In this case, is the second argument necessary here? It is passed in the StartNew method, but not actually used. Is there a scenario we need use this argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this argument if you want to cancel the Task. If you're application doesn't support or require cancellation then you could just say

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ... });
```

Note that cancellation is cooperative so your code must poll for cancellation and respond accordingly.

For example:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (...)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Body of for loop.
        }
    }, token);

    // ... elsewhere ...
    cts.Cancel();
```

You have to pass the cancellation token to the method otherwise it's not attached to the task. The code within method is only using the token to respond to cancelation, either throwing or using the IsCancellationRequested to shut down. Although a task could cancel itself from within the lambda I guess. The task itself needs the token too.

here's some further clarification:

> Passing a token into StartNew
>   associates the token with the Task. 
>   This has two primary benefits: 1) If
>   the token has cancellation requested
>   prior to the Task starting to execute,
>   the Task won't execute.  Rather than
>   transitioning to Running, it'll
>   immediately transition to Canceled. 
>   This avoids the costs of running the
>   task if it would just be canceled
>   while running anyway. 2) If the body
>   of the task is also monitoring the
>   cancellation token and throws an
>   OperationCanceledException containing
>   that token (which is what
>   ThrowIfCancellationRequested does),
>   then when the task sees that OCE, it
>   checks whether the OCE's token matches
>   the Task's token.  If it does, that
>   exception is viewed as an
>   acknowledgement of cooperative
>   cancellation and the Task transitions
>   to the Canceled state (rather than the
>   Faulted state).

From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/c2f614f6-c96c-4821-84cc-050b21aaee45

See general discussion of cancellation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx for further discussion.

Comment: I just think we can call token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() with my variable, we don't use it in the lambda as a parameter. Please don't give me wrong; if I declare a cancellationToken variable and don't pass it in the StartNew method, I can still use this variable to cancel my task, cannot I? 

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi Ade, I guess what Howard meant is like this: If I want to cancel a task, I can just use the cancellationToken in my lambda expression, since the cancellationToken is visible through the whole method. Now why do I have to pass it into the StartNew? Does the StartNew method use this token internally somehow?

Comment: I think this explains my question. I will try and thanks so much.